# Explaining predictable Network Interface Names

Tags: networking, server, hardware, interface

Hi after a lot of search I found this link: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

but still it does not help me for my case.
I have 2 onboard network interfaces and 1 network card with 2 interfaces on it.

when using `ip l` im seeing

```
eno1   
enp0s25  
enp2s0f0  
enp2s0f1
```

from the link:

> Names incorporating physical/geographical location of the connector of the hardware (example: enp2s0)

this confuses me. is `enp0s25` inboard or outboard ?

also please could you give me good examples of inboard and outboard names ?

Comment: Names can be different on different versions of the OS. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu server 20.04

Comment: can anyone else help too ?